# UIPageViewController reload data and update VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I already have my own page controller build on [this](http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-tutorial-using-uipageviewcontroller-create-content-slider-objective-cswift/) tutorial. 
How Can I reload my ViewController after my array was changed?

I want to reload and display only the existing items.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you posted no code, I'll assume you have done all as in the tutorial.
What you need, is make sure your array is not initialised with the ViewController, but separately. After that just `[self createPageViewController]` whenever you need to refresh it.

A better way would be to use:

```
 if([contentImages count])
 {
    NSArray *startingViewControllers = @[[self itemControllerForIndex: 0]];
    [pageController setViewControllers: startingViewControllers
                             direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                              animated: NO
                            completion: nil];
 }
```

I'm not able to test this out, but should work if the example is correct.

Comment: And what about dismiss VC's, do I need to do it before setVC's?

Comment: **maybe** I skipped that from the tutorial, if so, sorry just dissmis and call again. but if I didn't, you never present the ViewController, it's there the whole time, so no need to dismiss

Comment: I just checked it, and I had to remove subviews from my view to clean the background. And it works fine! Thank's =)